# Writing into a new column in excel file from list of string

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-csv, streamwriter, file-writing

I'm getting all the result in one single column but i want them in a new column

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms); 
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
{   
    for(int j = 0; j< myList[i].Count; j++)
    {
        tw.Write(myList[i][j]);
    }
    tw.WriteLine();
}
```

Result I'm getting:

> `Person1AddressPhone`

under single column

Result i want is:

> `Person1 |Address |Phone`
>
> mylist - new list1{person1, add1, phn1}, mylist - new list2{person2, add2, phn2}

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: StreamWriter is usually not used with Excel. Probably, you're trying to write into a delimited text file.

Comment: Looks like you're writing your own CSV writer? Don't bother; there are so many good libraries out there (csvhelper, lumenworks, servicestack). If you want to make excel files (XLSX), there are better libraries for that too (epplus, closedxml)

Comment: @MaciejLos, Yes, i'm writing a csv file generally we open it from excel so i mentioned both of them.

Comment: @CaiusJard, Is there a free and trustworthy one i mean i might have write large number of records so i'm creating my own one.

Comment: Edited the comment to mention some I've used; SO isn't a place for software recommendations, there is a dedicated SE site for that.. I currently use CsvHelper to read and write a half million line CSV were sent every week, and CSVH can read it async, de/ser it line by line (one object at a time) so it consumes minimal memory

Comment: In terms of trustworthy; look for one where you can see the source code then You can assess yourself how it works, whether it is good for you etc

Comment: @CaiusJard, Thank you for suggestions, is there any way to fix this code incase if i don't want to use third party library ?

Comment: You're writing 2D data with a single loop so it's fairly obvious to me why all the data appears in a single column? There isn't really enough info to give a decent answer, but you don't appear to be writing any delimiters, or line endings, unless they're already part of the data in the list, which we can't see either

Comment: @CaiusJard, sorry, i've edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Since in comment you mention that you are writing a csv file. I assumes you saved your file as .csv. You just need to add in your own delimiter.

```
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms);    

for(int j = 0; j< myList[i].Count; j++)
{
  tw.Write(myList[i][j]) ;
  if(j < myList[i].Count) tw.Write('|');
}
```

But of course there are a lot of libraries outside which does a better job. Like [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

Comment: that pipe sign is mean to be the column of excel sheet

Comment: Yes you are correct. By writing it that way. And you open up your .csv file with excel. You can choose your own delimiter. And they will fit nicely into excel column. And of course if you have a new row of data you have to write a new line.

Comment: Can I know what's the data in mylist looks like?

Comment: mylist - new list1{person1, add1, phn1}, mylist - new list2{person2, add2, phn2}

Comment: @crazyCoder all that information belongs into your question. that avoids that people have to spend time guessing and you can get a correct answer that solves your problem much much faster

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i've edited the question now.

Answer (score 0):

It worked. Thanks to @Anthony. I put comma instead of '|' sign and excel by default separated the column.